# NatTable layout formatting

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I've been battling with my NatTable layout for a while now...

The problem seems to be in a way it reacts with `GridLayout`.

I were able to produce almost satisfying result with `FillLayout`, the only problem with this layout is that it divides the full composite equally. Since these tables are not with equal length better would be to use GridLayout, to fit each table directly under last, in order to save space.
[image: FillLayout with Tables]

Requirement for these tables are following:

- Each table has to be fully expanded without scroller
- Main composite, where all the tables are sitting on has to be Scrollable Composite

Current code which I tried with `GridLayout`

```
Composite composite_1 = new Composite(compositeQuestionnaire, SWT.NONE);
    composite_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.TOP, SWT.TOP, false, false, 1, 1));

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);

    gridLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;   
    composite_1.setLayout(gridLayout);
```

And the result was pretty horrifing, all the tables were smashed together with scrollers. I couldn't find any way to resize them.

[image: GridLayout with NatTables]

Answer (score 0):

Try to grab horizontal and vertical excess space by passing the following parameters to the `GridData` constructor:

```
new GridData(SWT.TOP, SWT.TOP, true, true, 1, 1)
```

You can also control widget size by providing `heightHint` or `widthHint` in their GridData instance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your GridData is wrong. I usually use the GridDataFactory

```
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(natTable);
```